# Neat topology from messy model

Tags: topology, subdivision-surface

I'm hoping for some solid advice on how people sort out their topologies like they do on turbo squid.

For example on the image below (top) is a model I made a couple of years ago with some quite frankly hideous topology. The image below that (bottom) is just a random boat I saw on turbo squid with some absolutely top notch beautiful topology.

[image]

How is this done? Is this purely done from being tidy at the start of building or is this using another program such as meshlab / modifications in blender itself?

How would you go about creating something like this?

Comment: "*Is this purely done from being tidy at the start of building*" yes, mostly good planning and thinking ahead. You can't just "paste" good topology over a poorly made model. The topology*is* your model.

Comment: So there's no saving it. Make it again basically?

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose of doing a model is learning, start from scratch. Plan your topology carefully. Add detail where is needed and keep it simple where is supposed to be simple. Try as much as possible to keep your topology as
 quads. You will spend less time in a carefully planned model than trying to fix something that is poorly put together.

Adding to what @DuarteFarrajotaRamos said, topology should not be an afterthought or some form of wrapper, but the model itself.